# physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Trying to make my SKSpriteNode stay within the frame of a portrait only layout using edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame, and it only bounces off the left side of the frame and still leaves a gap....

Tried with "view", edgeLoopFromRect: frame, and it flew off the screen...

Any help would be appreciated..

```
func makeShip() {
    let ship = playerShip
    ship.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ship.frame.size)
    ship.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    ship.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ship.physicsBody!.mass = 0.08
    addChild(ship)
}


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    makeShip()
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame)
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Two questions.  Have you tried setting the `ship` physics body to `rectangleOfSize: ship.size`?  I'm not sure that you are looking for the frame (feel free to correct me).  And have you tried `ship.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true` to make sure that the ship cannot pop through the border?

Comment: yup i got it through the help of binarysubstrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)` try adding:

```
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
borderBody.friction = 0
self.physicsBody = borderBody
```